# Examples of generalisations in which $k$-ring might be, for example, a monad ? What are $\textit{scalars}$, really?

Tags: category-theory, monads, scalar-fields, semiring

I reflect on scalar nature so my question is very simple: **what are $\textit{scalars}$, really ?**

I read about *[ground ring](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ground+ring)*

> There are also generalisations in which k might be, for example, *a monad*. It is also important to consider base change from one ground ring to another, mediated by a ring homomorphism or even a bimodule.

The elements of the ground ring (or base ring) are called *scalars* but this is like saying, from an [inverse](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inverse) operation point of view, that a monad is division rings of scalars or subring of scalar matrices or as semiring.

I read also an interesting paper [Scalars, Monads, and Categories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.0585.pdf) that says

> These interrelations will be expressed in terms of
>   “triangles of adjunctions”, involving for instance various kinds of monoids
>   (non-commutative, commutative, involutive).

If we can use K-enriched category to rewrite scalar structure definition ..

> Every $K$-enriched category $C$ has an *underlying ordinary category*, usually denoted $C_0$, defined by $C_0(x,y) = K(I, hom(x,y))$ where $I$ is the unit object of $K$.

.. **what are $\textit{scalars}$, really ?**

Comment: What *specifically* don't you understand about the two references you link to? We may be able to help you with that, but the methodological or philosophical debate about what the term "scalar" should mean seems to me to be outside the scope of MSE.

Comment: From the linked paper's Introduction:
`Scalars are the elements s used in scalar multiplication s · v, yielding for instance
a new vector for a given vector v. Scalars are elements in some algebraic
structure, such as a field (for vector spaces), a ring (for modules), a group (for
group actions), or a monoid (for monoid actions).`

Comment: Yes.. but is not clear why scalars can be found in different places and also is not the same if scalars are in one and the scalar operations themselves produce different effects if they are in an algebraic structure instead of another. If the scalar is in a field, the dot product will not produce the same behavior as the scalar function (a vector is *rescaled*) if the scalar is instead in a ring, or monoid. I think that *scalar multiplication* is not equal to *dot product* because there is something between before scalar multiplication and after dot product , I think a Moduli space.

Comment: A functor is missing to explain how scalar can change position, a parameter space could be useful to explain, for example, of how a single operation can generate different projections since the output of a projection is just a vector (rememeber 'Helicity' ? ) In fact after dot product we have a real number, but before scalar multiplication we have not a real number also if scalar can be 'real' is not a 'scalar', is rescaled before with a parameter. Something was omitted : I think this is an (internalization)[https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internalization], there is a **internal category**

Comment: They says `Since any category with finite products is a cartesian monoidal category, monoids can also be internalized in the doctrine of categories with finite products. Monoids can also be internalized in the doctrine of multicategories. Rings can be internalized in the doctrine of categories with finite products`

Comment: So we have an internalization, in this way we can localize in what structure scalars can be. But this is a important situation